# Haskell - Average of Lists of Tuples

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell - Selectively Adding Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210225/haskell-selectively-adding-lists)

I have a data type:

```
data Film = Film String String Int [Rating]
     deriving (Show,Ord,Eq, Read)
```

A sample film:

```
("Ridley Scott","Alien",1979,[("Mark",5),("Zoe",3)])
```

How would I go about getting the average director rating across all films in a list of [Film]?

So if Ridley Scott had 2 films which both individually had an average score of 5 then he would score an overall average of 5.

I only have the code to work out a single Film

```
filmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
filmRating ratings = average (map snd ratings)
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you tried to write, please?

Comment: I only have the code to work out a single Film filmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
filmRating ratings = average (map snd ratings)

Comment: Write a function `Film -> Float` that will return average score of a film (use pattern matching). Then, write a function `[Film] -> Float` that will return average score of list of films (use `average` and previous function).

Comment: @sdcvvc: that's not what he wants to achieve. He wants the average score per director :)

Comment: See this earlier question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210225/haskell-selectively-adding-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a real answer, just some newbie notes.

You can use type aliases for `Director`, `Title` and all others types.

```
type Director = String
type Rate = Double
type Rater = String
type Ratings = [(Rater, Rate)]
type Title = String
type Year = Int

data Film = Film Director Director Year Ratings
     deriving (Show,Ord,Eq, Read)
```

That's why your `film` example should looks like:

`film = Film "Ridley Scott" "Alien" 1979 [("Mark",5),("Zoe",3)]`

If you have a function named `filmRating` it should be something like `:: Film -> Rate`:

```
filmRating :: Film -> Rate
filmRating (Film _ _ _ ratings) = average (map snd ratings)
```

> How would I go about getting the average director rating across all films in a list of [Film]?

You want something like `directorsAverageRate :: Director -> [Film] -> Rate`.

First of all, you need to filter films by `Director` value with some `:: Film -> Director` function. For this filtered list you simply get average rate with `average . (map filmRating)`.

---

**UPD**:

> I don't understand how to get the overall average after I have the films involved.

Let's take the definition of `average` function from the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376981/haskell-types-frustrating-a-simple-average-function):

```
average :: (Real a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
average xs = realToFrac (sum xs) / genericLength xs
```

Then

```
> let one_film = Film "Ridley Scott" "Alien" 1979 [("Mark",5),("Zoe",3)]
one_film :: Film

> let another_film = Film "Ridley Scott" "Alien2" 2979 [("Mark",4),("Zoe",2)]
another_film :: Film

> let films = [one_film, another_film]
films :: [Film]

> average . (map filmRating) $ films
3.5
it :: Double
```

Comment: Yup I understand the filtering but I don't understand how to get the overall average after I have the films involved.